# Include android.support.design.widget.NavigationView in layout file

Tags: android

I am developing android app and i have a navigation drawer. My question is rather than writing same code in every page ( As i am using activities not fragments ) i need to have it somewhere in layout file and include it in other files. Like :
I have a layout file for navigation bar like this :

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/tools" />
```

btw it shows an error for defining layout height and width.

And i need to include same in other layout files like this :

```
<include layout="@layout/navigation_view" />
```

How to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create BaseActivity and extend other activities from it. This idea was used in Google's [iosched](https://github.com/google/iosched) app. It doesn't use NavigationView, but you can get the main idea about activitie's hierarchy.

Basically, the layout for BaseActivity should look like

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  tools:openDrawer="start">

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Of course, you may add appbar, if you need.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file add a FrameLayout e.g.

```
 <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/myView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

As you are using fragments so in your activity file:

Add imports:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

And add code:

```
FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;

mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
```

And Finally replace your FrameLayout with the fragment:

```
mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.myView, new Fragment()).commit();
```